# Facebook Connect <fb:login-button> No Longer Firing Callback (As of today)

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml

Came into the office today to do some more work on my nearly completed Facebook Connect website application.

And i have discovered for some reason, the "**onlogin**" event of the **fb:login** button FBML control is no longer getting fired!!?!

To anyone else that has a Facebook Connect FBML app (and using the JavaScript API for authentication), i would advise you test your application to make sure it's still working.

A friend of mine's app (which is live) has also stopped working as of today.

What's happening is you click on the "Connect to Facebook" button, it shows the FB login dialog, you log in.

Yes, they are being logged in to Facebook correctly (thankfully), but the "onlogin" callback event is not getting fired anymore, so the page just sits there (where before the "onlogin" event would redirect to the homepage, for example).

Of course if you refresh, you are logged into Facebook.

Seriously, WTF - what have those developers at Facebook done now?!?!.

Any ideas? Has anyone read any updates/threads on this issue?

**UPDATE:**

8 hours and still no fix in place. I've tried to do some workarounds (there is also an onclick event of the FBML Login Button), but it's all too early in the authentication cycle.

We need to be able to hook into a post-login callback to do things like redirects, permission popups, authentication logic, etc.

Nothing we can do without Facebook fixing this.

I just hope when i come in the office tomorrow this will be 'magically' fixed, much like this issue 'magically' appeared.

Well judging by the comments here i'm not alone. It's obvious at this point that Facebook have made a change somewhere, without telling us.

I just hope they rectify this issue ASAP as there is no workaround i can see for this.

**UPDATE 2**

Yep - (drum roll), its **yet ANOTHER bug** from that team of world-class developers at Facebook: (thanks Anon for finding link) http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11733

I love it how the comment from the FB guy Marc says "Only seems to be happening on old Facebook Javascript SDK", well, enable us to do server-side authentication with your Graph API (instead of just for retrieving user details/posting), and we wont have to use the old JavaScript API!

Fun and games.

**FINAL UPDATE**

Facebook have (seemingly) fixed this.

Let's hope it stays fixed.

Given the 'correct' answer to Anon (as he found the link).

Comment: This what bad dreams are made of. Have heard FB changes stuff overnight and often.

Comment: @DmMin, what can one say. It's like a lucky dip (or unlucky dip)

Comment: I am still having this problem.. does the bug strikes again ?

Comment: They're making changes, i can tell - because random things are happening. I now get a popup with my own website and the session id in the URL??? idiots.

Comment: old api sucked way too much.. I'm switching to new graph api. hope they wont break it without notification :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please confirm and vote on this bug... this should be fixed asap!!

http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11733

Comment: Hehehe, well at least we have confirmation. Now we play the waiting game.

Answer (score 2):

if in FB.getLoginStatus you are passing second parameter as true, pls make it to false.
I resolved callback issue using this trick.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and they are about to fix it